# How do I get stylesheet to work in my Express project?

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

I have a stylesheet I created in the "public" directory of my express app. It is called app.css.

I've added a link tag to an ejs file, where I want the style to apply.

It will not apply the style.

I have told express to serve the public directory with an app.use as you can see in my code below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));



app.get("/mynameis/:name", function(req, res){
var name = req.params.name;
res.render("app.ejs", {name: name});
});

app.get("/posts", function(req, res){
var posts = [
    {band: "Led Zeppelin", album: "Houses Of The holy"},
    {band: "Pink Floyd", album: "Animals"}


];
res.render("posts.ejs", {posts:posts});
})
```

The ejs file looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

<h1> The Posts Page</h1>

<% for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){ %>
 <li><%= posts[i].band %> - <%= posts[i].album %> </li>

                            <% }; %>
```

The css looks like this:

```
body {
background:blue;
}
```

What is going on? Why won't the ejs file recognize my stylesheet?

Comment: My bad, actually the `public` should not be part of the url, you might just need to add a `/` before the file name

Comment: its colt steele web dev bootcap. And i changed its to public/app.css and restarted the server and still nothing.

Comment: i tried adding just the slash too, nothing. im stumped.

Comment: Can you check in the browser dev tool (F12) and the network part, find the request that fails to see what's the problem, or in the console to see what's the error

Comment: Also your the link should contain `type="text/css"`. And it should be in `<head>` tags

Comment: The ejs file needs to contains the code for an actual html page. Maybe it's not styled because there is no body to apply style one. You add `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags

Comment: all i can say is i watched a video of putting the exact code as I originally typed it, and it worked there were no head tags nothing. im not denying what youre sayng i just dont get why it isnt working as it should

Comment: You need a `<body>` if you want to apply a style on a `body`. If you check the source code of your page in the browser (Ctrl + U), is there a `<body>` ?

Comment: yes inspecting it on chrome shows that the text is in the body

Comment: and what does the network tab displays about the request to retrieve the css file ?

Comment: it says: 

2
posts:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://robbiecontainer-chgqe.run-us-west2.goorm.io/public/app.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: That's because you have to set the type `type="text/css"`. Here is how the link shoud look `<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: ok im gonna give it a try. btw, when i edit an ejs file...if i restart the server by running node app.js (the main file), will that update the ejs files too? or do i just hit command save when i alter an ejs file?

Comment: yes you need to save your files and restart the server if you are using node. If you use `nodemon` you can just save files and it will restart alone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212657/discussion-between-nineborn-and-mickael-b).

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues but this line helped me:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

It also looks like you're missing a "/" in front of app.css. Right now, it is being read as "publicapp.css", so you need the forward-slash to make it "public/app.css".

I hope that helps